# many AppCenter apps cannot access my (real) home directory!

Tags: appcenter, elementary-project, flatpak

I have now installed a number of uncurated apps from the AppCenter, but upon trying to open or save files with them, I find myself looking at a flatpak "containerized" version of my /home/username directory with nothing in it (and files created there don't show up anywhere that I can find in my real home directory tree either, even in ~/.local, ~/.var etc.).

This obviously doesn't happen with the curated apps that Elementary comes with, but I don't want it to happen with any AppCenter apps since most apps are plainly pretty useless if I can't access my own files while using them.

Can someone please tell me what is going on and how I can stop this really bizarre behavior that I've only encountered since "upgrading" to Horus? Otherwise, I am very likely to give up on Elementary completely and just go with Ubuntu (and I doubt I'm the only one).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve generally used [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) to manage the permissions of Flatpak applications. It’s a pretty decent tool that will solve 99% of the issues that commonly affect containerized applications

Comment: Thank you! After setting it to allow access to "all user files" and explicitly allowing it to access the symbolic link in my home directory to my second disk drive mount point, it seems to be behaving sanely. I still can't help but wonder why anyone would not make access to all user files the default for their package, however ...